# Excel Array Formula If Statement that Returns the Value that Matches a Condition

Tags: arrays, excel

I have an array formula in excel of this form:

```
=IF(ABS(range-0.25)<0.1,1,0)
```

Which basically looks through the entire row defined as `range` for a value within 0.1 of 0.25. If it finds something that meets this condition, it just prints the number 1.

What I would like it to do is print the index in `range` at which the value that matches this condition is found. So for example, if the 11th value in `range` is .2505 (which matches my condition), I would like the output to be 11. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula solution, does not require array entry:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ABS(range-0.25)<0.1,),0)
```

Note that it will return an error if nothing matches your condition.  You can avoid that by wrapping it in `IFERROR`